# How to get mismatch position using Linq or lambda operation on two string array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
string[] list1 = { "a", "c", "b", "d", "f", "e" };
string[] list2 = { "a", "c", "b1", "d1", "f", "e" };
```

Is there any way we can compare both the string array and get the mismatch position with linq or lambda expression.

Here I am expecting position 2 and 3 which is not matching (b not equals to b1 and d not equals to d1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mismatches = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(list1.Length, list2.Length))
                           .Where(i => list1[i] != list2[i])
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this is what I was expecting. one more thing I am writing one if condition on top of it when list1[0] is equals to list2[0] then only do the operation (your suggestion)or else escape it. can that if condition we can merge it with your queary

Comment: When `list1[0] != list2[0]`, do you want to return everything (all the indices), or nothing (an empty collection)?

Comment: if (list1[0]==list2[0])
{
   var mismatches = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(list1.Length, list2.Length)).Where(i => list1[i] != list2[i]).ToList();
}                                                                   currently I am writing my code like this way I want to merge that if condition inside the suggested approach by you if possible.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of doing that (rather than preserving your `if`), but you could use `Where(i => list1[0] == list2[0] && list1[i] != list2[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

If the element counts are the same in both lists then you can do

```
var result = list1.Where((x,idx) => x != list2[idx]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to come up with simpler solution and here what i've got:

```
var mismatchIndexes in list1.Except(list2)
            .Where(s => list1.First() == list2.First())
            .Select(s => Array.IndexOf(list1, s)).ToList();
```

When the first two elements in arrays (list1, list2) are diffrent there in no output and with the given example the output is 2 and 3